# How to show element when value in input doesn't found in a list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I created search input to search some items inside a list. I want that if the item search isn't inside the list to show add button like in the html code:

```
<div ng-controller="foodCtrl">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row foodGroupp" >
            <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">food</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFood" ng-model="inputFood" placeholder="Write some food"  ng-keyup="doCheck()">
            </div>
            <span id="addIcon" ng-show="showIcon">
                <button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
            </span>
            <ul ng-show="inputFood" id="foodList">
                <li ng-repeat="foodN in foodName | filter : inputFood">
                        <span>{{ foodN.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">הוסף</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

The javascript code look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('foodCtrl',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.foods = [];
    $scope.foodName = [];

    $http.get('/files/foodName.json')
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.foodName = response;
    });

    $scope.showIcon = false;

    $scope.doCheck = function(){
        $(function () {
            if($scope.inputFood != ""){
                var sizeOfList = $("#foodList").find("li").length;

                if(sizeOfList == 0){
                    console.log("sizeOfList " +sizeOfList);
                    $scope.showIcon = true;
                }

            }else{
                $scope.showIcon = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It doesn't work correctly. If the length of the value is one or the list is shown it still show me the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direct show your button according to your filter data.

HTML CODE

```
<div ng-controller="foodCtrl">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row foodGroupp" >
            <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">food</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFood" ng-model="inputFood" placeholder="Write some food"  ng-keyup="doCheck()">
            </div>
            <span id="addIcon" ng-hide="(foodName|filter:inputFood).length > 0">
                <button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
            </span>
            <ul ng-show="inputFood" id="foodList">
                <li ng-repeat="foodN in foodName | filter : inputFood">
                        <span>{{ foodN.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">הוסף</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here at the code snippet.Nothing changed.

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('foodCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.foods = [];
  $scope.foodName = [];

  //$http.get('/files/foodName.json')
  //  .success(function(response) {
  //    $scope.foodName = response;
  //  });

  $scope.foodName = [{
    name: 'test1'
  }, {
    name: 'test2'
  }, {
    name: 'test3'
  }];
  $scope.showIcon = false;

  $scope.doCheck = function() {
    if ($scope.inputFood != "") {
      var sizeOfList = $("#foodList").find("li").length;

      if (sizeOfList == 0) {
        console.log("sizeOfList " + sizeOfList);
        $scope.showIcon = true;
      }

    } else {
      $scope.showIcon = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="foodCtrl">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row foodGroupp">
        <label for="inputFood" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">food</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="atext" class="form-control" id="inputFood" ng-model="inputFood" placeholder="Write some food" ng-keyup="doCheck()">
        </div>
        <span id="addIcon" ng-show="showIcon">
                <button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
            </span>
        <ul ng-show="inputFood" id="foodList">
          <li ng-repeat="foodN in foodName | filter : inputFood">
            <span>{{ foodN.name}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">הוסף</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the result from the json files doesn't show. if you see the result you would notice that even that your search is inside the data the button is still show. at least for one parameter.